# Свойство margin-right, не сдвигается блок

Tags: css

Данная конструкция отказывается работать:

```
<style>
.myblock{ 
width:150px; 
height:150px; 
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.7); 
margin-right:-150px; 
}
</style>
<div class="myblock"></div>
```

Да, можно использовать `margin-left`, но он отлично работает со всеми значениями, как со знаком, так и без. В чем моя проблема?

Comment: для `display:inline-block` код будет работать. Возможно просто не так как вы ожидаете. Можете показать ожидаемое поведение для отрицательного margin-right?

Comment: margin-left:150px;

Comment: тогда используйте margin-left.  Вообще для позиционирования лучше использовать специальные инструменты.

Comment: если вы про position:relative и последующее использование top bottom right left то тут несколько проблематичнее ибо физически он остался на месте а визуально съехал

Comment: вариантов позиционирования может быть множество, и выбор конкретного зависит от конкретной разметки, и конкретного вида который нужно получить

Answer (score 1):

Мое мнение, почему так происходит:

1. Потому, что браузер считает справа налево относительно меня

поэтому `margin-left`  и работает

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.myblock {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);  
  margin-left: 150px;   
}
```

```html
<div class="myblock"></div>
```

2. Для того, чтобы `margin-right` заработал необходимо его прижать к правому краю

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.myblock {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
  float: right;
  margin-right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myblock"></div>
```

Comment: мне раньше казалось года 3-4 назад что "моя" конструкция работала

Comment: по логике он должен сработать как *margin-left: 150px;* только *margin-right: -150px;*, а у вас иной результат

Comment: если ширина   блока 100% margin-right также будет работать

Comment: ширина родительского блока? или текущего?